# detecting changes between two images (detecting appearances of new objects)

Tags: java, image, image-processing

This is my first question on Stackoverflow, so at first - hi everyone :)

I'm a newbie in image processing, but I have to write an app (in Java) to detect changes between images from a camera (or rather to detect new objects on images).
A camera is taking a picture every minute, all day, so as an input I have a sequence of color images in JPG.
The important things are:

1. the camera isn't moving, so a background doesn't change. I'm interested only in
   detecting objects (e.g. people, animals, cars, ..) between lens and a background
2. it should be impervious to image noise from a camera or weather (e.g. rain, snow, sun moving - shades)
3. the only thing I need as an output is an information that sth has changed between two images

I'm interested in as simple solution as possible, but it has to be a working solution.
It doesn't need to be infallible, but it should work correctly in most normal cases.

Of course, I don't expect someone give me a ready to use snippet of a code
(although that would be great!  ;) ), but if someone, who knows the topic, gives me some guidelines (steps to do, algorithms or articles to read), I'll be really gratefull. I haven't found nothing appropriate on google and unfortunately I don't have a year to read few books and do a PhD to find a solution :)

Answer (score 1):

1. you can parse md5 of the image and compare parts of it, and check if they are similar or not, you can refer to [this](https://github.com/jenssegers/imagehash)
2. You can use **Keypoint Matching** which is almost the same method as 1 you can read about this.
3. Read about **Histogram method**

Comment: You can't parse an MD5... And an MD5 will be extremely susceptible to image noise.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, just subtract one image from the other and look at the differences. Ignore small changes and try to build area of movement and just accept bigger areas.